# Condense Multiple Nested For Loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, optimization

I have a relatively small `std::unordered_map<char, int>` of only 8 characters. However, I would like to iterate through them and set each character to a value 0-9.

The chars are `d, e, m, n, o, r, s, y`.

I COULD do something along the lines of:

```
std::unordered_map<char, int> letters;
for(int d = 0; d < 10; ++d)
    for(int e = 0; e < 10; ++e)
        for(int m = 0; m < 10; ++m)
            // continued
            letters['d'] = d; // etc...
```

But this does not seem prudent at all, and becomes more and more tedious as the letter count increases. There must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: `e` and `m` are never used in the loop, so why not simplify to just one loop over `d` ?

Comment: If i got the OP right, `//etc...` stands for `letters['e']=e; letters['m']=m;...`

Comment: Maybe, but he asked for a simplification, and your interpretation will wipe the values on every iteration rendering it useless -- but you are right and I'm not sure if he asking for a better way of writing bad code, or a way to fix the bad code.

Answer (score 2):

If i got you right, you want to iterate through every possible combination, how the values 0-9 can be assigned to 8 letters.

In this case a nice property of our numbers comes to mind: we use a decimal system. So you are looking for ever number with 8 digits and then pair every digit with a letter:

```
00000000 - 99999999
||||||||   ||||||||
demnorsy   demnorsy
```

Of course you can do the same with other numbers of digits, but its very easy to see the idea in decimal.

So the easy way is:

```
std::unordered_map<char, int> letters;
std::vector<char> chars= {'d', 'e', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 'y'};
for (int N=0; N<pow(10,chars.size()); ++N){
    for(int i=0; i<chars.size();++i)
        letters[chars[i]] = (N/pow(10,i))%10; //integer division

    //whatever you want to do with your permutation, do it here
}
```

Comment: The `letters[chars[i]] = ...` overrides the same element in every loop wiping the data from the previous iteration -- is that the intent?

Comment: @Soren: Since the OP has only one map and does the same, i think so. Thats also why i added a comment "use permutation here".